# Java ArrayList add item outside current size

Tags: java, arraylist

Wondering whether there is an efficient way to add an item to Java's ArrayList at a bigger position than its current size:

Scenario:

```
   ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>;
   ... let's say I add three elements
```

Now I would like to add an item at position 10 (leaving items from 3 to 10 to null)

```
  items.add(10,newItem);  // item.size() == 3
```

Is there an efficient way resizing/filling an ArrayList with nulls?

Java's implementation makes size field private :-(..

Comment: You should probably use HashMap or SortedMap instead.

Comment: Ok, using a Map is not a solution for memory raisons, we know at the end the structure is full -> TIntObjectHashMap (trove) maybe

Comment: A HashMap does not support order. A SortedMap is a better option.

Comment: What memory reasons? Why would you assume that a Map is using significantly more memory than a list?

Comment: Do you know your max possible size? Could you use an array?

Comment: One way would be to call `add(null)` 8 times.

Comment: Check the implementation of HashMap and you'll see (it's holding key.value and some structures). Really not an option when you want to put mio of objects. Bad luck size is not known

Comment: Then either call `add(null)` 8 times as ortang suggests, or create a `ForwardingList` that does it for you.

Comment: Just as a question, what would you have done if the size field was not private (given that there is a size() method to get it)? Attempted to just set the size? Would you have done this without updating the size of the underlying array? Seems like a really bad idea. Probably why it is private (other than the notation that being non-private is just a bad idea in general).

Comment: calling first ensureCapacity(), which is actually creating an array with the new capacity (extra size is filled with zero). So seting the actual size to the capacity seems ok. That's assuming you're using Oracle JDK which is why using private method by reflection is not a good idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imho the best thing you can do is `items.addAll(Collections.nCopies(6, null))` and hope, that ArrayList implements some behaviour to internally fasten this up

Comment: This is nice but a bit scary from a performance point of view

Comment: well nCopies only produces a list-Wrapper for an Array and this way your ArrayList is able to use System.arraycopy to fill in the null's depending on how smart it is implemented

Comment: public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
 Object[] a = c.toArray();
        int numNew = a.length;
 ensureCapacity(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
        size += numNew;
 return numNew != 0;
    }

Comment: Voila, but your solution it's the best one of the proposition so far :-)

Comment: so where exactly is this "from a performance point of view" scary, comparing to calling add(null) many times (if we suppose the numbers arent fix)?

Comment: since nCopies creates an immutable list (thats not much more than an array underlying), toArray just copies an entire array; calling n times add(null) with a big n (> capacity) causes the ArrayList to copy its internal array into a bigger array; possibly more than once; yeah you can increase capacity before adding, but you still don't get much more performance and have an unreadable code

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

items.add(new Item(0));
items.add(new Item(1));
items.add(new Item(2));

items.addAll(Collections.<Item>nCopies(7, null));
items.add(10,new Item(10));

System.out.println(items);
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 10]
```

Comment: Use `10 - items.size` instead of `7` as a more robust option.

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but you can now use `SparseArray` as an (almost) direct drop-in replacement for `ArrayList`.  It allows non-contiguous integer key values, and returns null if a value has not been set for a key. Performance-wise it was designed *exactly* for your needs.  Instead of `add` you use `append`, which is more descriptive in that you are appending to the end of whatever the max key is, even if there is gaps.  You can also `set` at any key value you'd like, even if it is beyond the maximum key.

Answer (score 1):

Use TreeMap instead. Here is simple example to check memony consuption. Run first and second test separatly and use jvisualvm to check heap size. Remember to Perform GC several times.

```
    public class Test {


            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
                String s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque metus.";


                //Test 1
                ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                    l.add(s + " " + i);
                    l.addAll(Collections.nCopies(i % 10, (String)null)); //Add some nulls
                }
                //Heap is > 5MB

                //Test 2 uncomment and comment test 1
    //          SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    //          for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    //              map.put(i,s + " " + i);
    //          }
                //Heap is < 5MB

                Thread.sleep(100000);

            }
    }
```

It looks like `TreeMap` version is even less memory consuming than ArrayList version. Check yourself.

Comment: Peter, ArrayList is an array and little more. How is possible a full array takes more size than any other structure ? ... I think your example has a problem (I'm certain)

Comment: The array is (s - string, n- null): s n s n n s n n n s n n n n s n n n n n s n n n n n n s n n n n n n n s ... etc There is lot of memory reserved for references but set to null. TreeMap doesn't have this problem. As you said it's an array. Even array of 1mio nulls still costs memory. It's all about how "dense" is your list.

Comment: If it's a full array, whre is the problem? Put some nulls using `Collection.nCopies` method.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem, once the filling is finished there are no anymore nulls. To check the size is more like :

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                    l.add(s + " " + i);
}

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range
>   (index < 0 || index > size())

Comment: Unable to edit. Correct link is : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead of a List here. This will allow for indexes to not exist:

```
SorteMap<Integer, Item> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Map>();
int i=0;
myMap.put(i++, first);
myMap.put(i++, second);
myMap.put(i++, third);
myMap.put(10, other);
```

If a Map truly will not work, as you stated. I would then suggest creating a Decorator around ArrayList. In the insert method, add nulls to fill the empty locations. I would suggest using Guava's [ForwardingList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) to ease the creation of the class. This way you would only have to implement one method.

Comment: TreeMap with 1mio Object is large.

Comment: ArrayList with 1mio Objects and nulls in the middle is much smaller?

Comment: The ArrayList is mainly full.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this,
But if you wish to do that, then add empty object in remaining index such as..

```
    ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();
    items.add(new Object());
    items.add(new Object());
    items.add(new Object());
    items.add(3,new Object());
```

Comment: actually I was lucking for something a bit more elegant :-)

Answer (score 0):

If memory and index is so important that use a normal array.

When it becomes to small use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) thats the way ArrayList does it internal.

--

Even if you use the ArrayList and have a Million Objects it is advisable to use the ArrayList(int initialCapacity)-Constructor to avoid a lot of copy-operations

Answer (score 0):

@icCube- you said, that list should be about 90% full. 
My idea for this solution is:

- If you exactly know target size - use plain array
- If you are aware of target size - use ArrayList with initial capacity as close as possible to target size. Put nulls with `l.addAll(Collections.nCopies(n, (String)null));` as people said.
- If you don't know target size - your ArrayList will be resized many times. Resizing means copying whole underlying array (it uses Arrays.copyOf). You can imagine what happens if array is copied around - GC has lots of work. Use TreeMap then.

Answer (score -2):

Use constructor `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`. This way you can set an initial capacity.

Comment: InitialCapacity is not the size -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 0

Comment: Try :    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(10);
        list.add(9,3);
    }