# Adding elements into ArrayList at position larger than the current size

Tags: java, data-structures

Currently I'm using an ArrayList to store a list of elements, whereby I will need to insert new elements at specific positions. There is a need for me to enter elements at a position larger than the current size. For e.g:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add(3,"hi");
```

Now I already know there will be an OutOfBoundsException. Is there another way or another object where I can do this while still keeping the order? This is because I have methods that finds elements based on their index. For e.g.:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("hi");
arr.add(0,"hello");
```

I would expect to find "hi" at index 1 instead of index 0 now. 
So in summary, short of manually inserting null into the elements in-between, is there any way to satisfy these two requirements:

- Insert elements into position larger than current size
- Push existing elements to the right when I insert elements in the middle of the list

I've looked at [Java ArrayList add item outside current size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925128/java-arraylist-add-item-outside-current-size), as well as HashMap, but HashMap doesn't satisfy my second criteria. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Performance is not really an issue right now.

UPDATE: There have been some questions on why I have these particular requirements, it is because I'm working on operational transformation, where I'm inserting a set of operations into, say, my list (a math formula). Each operation contains a string. As I insert/delete strings into my list, I will dynamically update the unapplied operations (if necessary) through the tracking of each operation that has already been applied. My current solution now is to use a subclass of ArrayList and override some of the methods. I would certainly like to know if there is a more elegant way of doing so though.

Comment: If I use hashmap, the keys do not change their order when I insert an element in the middle of the list. The key for "hi" will remain at 0 instead of 1, which is what I need.

Comment: @WeiHao I believe you need to whip your own method checking for bounds and inserting null in between.  I hope having the array size equal to the new bounds is okay with you.

Comment: I don't see any easy option here. You could rebuild a map every time you want to shift, not that costly to do, but you will somehow need to keep track of all the elements. You could make a linked list and insert nulls between, but then you get method will probably have to be a straight search from the bottom or top, which is a bit expensive. Or you can write some tricky code to make the arraylist work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your requirements are contradictory:

> ... I will need to insert new elements at specific positions.
>
> There is a need for me to enter elements at a position larger than the current size.

These imply that positions are stable; i.e. that an element at a given position remains at that position.

> I would expect to find "hi" at index 1 instead of index 0 now.

This states that positions are not stable under some circumstances.

You really need to make up your mind which alternative you need.

- If you must have stable positions, use a `TreeMap` or `HashMap`.  (A `TreeMap` allows you to iterate the keys in order, but at the cost of more expensive insertion and lookup ... for a large collection.)  If necessary, use a "position" key type that allows you to "always" generate a new key that goes between any existing pair of keys.
- If you don't have to have stable positions, use an `ArrayList`, and deal with the case where you have to insert beyond the end position using `append`.

I fail to see how it is sensible for positions to be stable if you insert beyond the end, and allow instability if you insert in the middle.  (Besides, the latter is going to make the former unstable eventually ...)

Comment: Great! Never thought like that. +1 for contradiction in question ;)

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that positions are definitely not stable. In fact, they are very dynamic. I'm actually working on operational transformation, so I'm looking for a list that can store strings dynamically. So this list will constantly have inserts or deletes at various positions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation for a rough idea on why I need the positions to be dynamic.

Comment: @WeiHao - so there's your answer.  Use an ArrayList, and when you need to add a String at a position greater than 'list.size()', just call `list.append(str)`.

Comment: @StephenC: But appending will only add it to the last position of the arraylist. For e.g., I may need to add to position 10 when the ArrayList only has 5 elements.

Comment: @WeiHao - You have entirely missed my point.  If positions are unstable, they change each time you insert / delete.  So inserting at position N is only meaningful if 1) you have looked up just previously what is at that position, or 2) you have carefully been tracking the positions.  And the latter is only practical if you make the insertions / deletions in a specific order.  You are either not explaining something, or you are misunderstanding the fundamental nature of the problem / dilema I'm talking about in my answer.

Comment: @WeiHao - Or think about it this way.  Suppose you have a sequence of inserts / deletes to do.  Does (say) insert at position N mean immediately before the element at position N 1) before we started the sequence, 2) now, or 3) when we've finished (if that makes any sense ...).  The point is ... if the position numbers are unstable, then "insert at position N" is a problematic (ill-defined) operation, when you consider a sequence of operations.

Comment: @StephenC: Ah, I see the basis for your confusion now. This is because I think you aren't sure of the nature of operational transformation. Insert at position N would mean immediately after the element at position N before we started the sequence, based on the last known list. As we apply each insert/delete, we will track it and if subsequent insert/deletes are affected, we will "transform" the incoming inserts/deletes to take into account the new position that it now needs to go into in order to preserve the intention of the original insert/delete.

Comment: Since there are no new answers, I'll take yours as the best possible answer, although it doesn't exactly suit my requirements. It certainly is thought-provoking though.

Answer (score 3):

even you can use TreeMap for maintaining order of keys.

Comment: But if you want to allow for gaps and shifting of elements, I don't see how this will help you here.

Comment: come on, tree will help you for maintaining order, now shifting can be done by programing.

Comment: @SatyajitsinhRaijada: but OP wants to address the element by index - using the tree, you'd have to manually adjust all the keys in order to shift (compared with the array list, where the index is implied by the position, and the shifting up can be done by an array copy).

Comment: Greg is right. If I use TreeMap I still need to adjust the keys manually, which will cause an issue as the list gets larger. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, I would say use `Map` instead of List. I guess your problem can be solved in better way if you use `Map`.  But in any case if you really want to do this with `Arraylist`

```
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(); //Create empty list
        a.addAll(Arrays.asList( new String[100]));  // add n number of strings, actually null . here n is 100, but you will have to decide the ideal value of this, depending upon your requirement.
        a.add(7,"hello");
        a.add(2,"hi");
        a.add(1,"hi2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Vector class to solve this issue.

Vector vector = new Vector();
**vector.setSize(100);**

vector.set(98, "a");

When "setSize" is set to 100 then all 100 elements gets initialized with null values.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still dealing with this, you may do it like this.

```
Object[] array= new Object[10];
array[0]="1";
array[3]= "3";
array[2]="2";
array[7]="7";

List<Object> list= Arrays.asList(array);
```

But the thing is you need to identify the total size first, this should be just a comment but I do not have much reputation to do that.